# Docker and Traefik different directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have 2 different directories each containing docker containers for different purposes and both spun up with docker compose.

Dir A has Traefik config and container (and other containers) as well as environment variables whereas Dir B is a bunch of containers.

I want to now include Traefik labels in Dir B containers but when I run compose in Dir B, I'm facing:

```
WARN[0000] The "DOMAIN_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
service "[service name]" refers to undefined network traefik_proxy: invalid compose project
```

I'm guessing this is because services in Dir B can't see traefik_proxy since it's part of a different stack and same with the DOMAIN_NAME variable.

How can I have Dir B 'reach across' to Dir A? Is it even possible with my current config?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple compose projects share a single Traefik frontend, that's certainly possible, but you need to place Traefik on a shared network.  For this model, I would suggest starting with a `docker-compose.yaml` that *only* deploys Traefik; e.g:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: docker.io/traefik:latest
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --accesslog=true
      - --accesslog.filepath=/dev/stderr
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "127.0.0.2:8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

networks:
  services:
    external: true
```

Start by creating the shared network:

```
docker network create services
```

And then starting the Traefik project:

```
pushd traefik; docker-compose up -d; popd
```

Now for every project you want to make available via Traefik, put your services on the `services` network. For example, let's say we have this in `app1/docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app1:
    image: docker.io/containous/whoami
    networks:
      - services
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=PathPrefix(`/app1`)"


networks:
  services:
    external: true
```

Then I can run:

```
pushd app1; docker-compose up -d; popd
```

And now my `app1` service is available at `http://localhost/app1/`.

We can add as many services as we want like this; the only requirement is that the containers are attached to the `services` network.

Comment: I've made a complete test environment available [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-74187101).

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed reply. I will give it a go.